# EF Core: update database error: relation "Owner" already exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I try to add migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

and then update the database:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

But, I get an error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
[21:59:12 INF] OnConfigure finish
Applying migration '20201029182606_InitialCreate'.
```

> Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> CREATE TABLE "Owner" (
> "Id" integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
> reputation integer NOT NULL,
> user_id integer NOT NULL,
> user_type text NULL,
> profile_image text NULL,
> display_name text NULL,
> link text NULL,
> accept_rate integer NULL,
> CONSTRAINT "PK_Owner" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
> );
>
> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "Owner" already exists
>
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>
> Exception data:
> Severity: ERROR
> SqlState: 42P07
> MessageText: relation "Owner" already exists
> File: heap.c
> Line: 1155
> Routine: heap_create_with_catalog
> 42P07: relation "Owner" already exists

[Here on my github](https://github.com/LightVolk/QuestionServiceWebApi/blob/master/Models/Search.cs) i store model (and other source code of service).
I remove 'EnsureCreate' code from ApplicationContext file.

How to solve this error?
Thank you!

P.S. I remove file appsettings.json where store connetion string:

```
 {
"Logging": {
 "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Information",
   "Microsoft": "Warning",
   "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
 }
},
 "AllowedHosts": "*",
 "ConnectionStrings": {
  "Questions": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=questiondb;Username=postgres;Password=password"
 },
  "Tags": [
   "ef core",
   "c#",
   "asp.net core",
   "asp.net core webapi"
  ]
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your line 38 I see a problem where you use filed but you need to use the property.

```
public Owner Owner { get; set; }
```

But you use

```
public Owner owner { get; set; }
```

and that's a problem.

Another solution: as I understand to see your problem that owner table relation already exists. So delete unnecessary relation or use Fluent Api.

Comment: Thank you! I change file, drop tables and make database update. And it works

Answer (score 1):

Delete `Owner` table using DB Management Studio or command line then run migration again.